# How to PHP-Include from Root of Domain?

Tags: php, include, include-path, php-include

I have a `file.php` located in `www.example.com/folder/`.

I want that file to use include command for files located in `www.example.com/include/`.

If I simply use:

`<?php include './include/footer.php';?>`

It doesn't work, as it will try to search in the physical folder where the `file.php` is located, while I need it to refer to the root of my domain.

Comment: Use a second dot to traverse into parent directory: `<?php include '../include/footer.php';?>`.

Comment: that worked, but i guess that this is considering that i want to go only one level up, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Here's the [server documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

Together, it should look like this:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/include/footer.php";
```

Comment: what does that mean? simply use this exact line, right before my current line?

Comment: Use include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/include/footer.php";